# plotting the most represented node in my igraph object in R

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I have the fblog data set that is about french political party blogs.and is an object of igraph
I just want to plot the most represented party(node) in my the set 
I used degree as below,
but now I dont know how to use it to plot it
I want just to show 20 of most important party(nodes) in my graph and plot them.
I hope you can help me

```
 deg_g <-sort(igraph::degree(fblog, mode = "all", normalized = T),decreasing = TRUE)
class(deg_g)
UU<-deg_g[1:20]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the subgraph, you need to know *which* nodes have the highest degree,  not what their degree is.  Once you have that, you can just use `induced_subgraph`.

```
library(igraph)
library(sand)
data(fblog)
fblog = upgrade_graph(fblog)

DEG <-order(igraph::degree(fblog, mode = "all", normalized = T),
             decreasing = TRUE)

HighDeg = induced_subgraph(fblog, DEG[1:20])
plot(HighDeg)
```

[image: Subgraph of nodes with high degree]

I am sure that you can layout the graph to make it prettier, but this is the subgraph that you requested.